# Doctrine entity collection is null after database request

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use the collection on entity in my symfony application 3.3.5
My configuration works fine when I create a new object and add collection in it.
But when I am trying to get an existing collection from database, it is always null.
My entities looks like this

```
class HydraulicTest
{ 
...
/**
 * @var \Me\MyBundle\Entity\HydraulicTestResult
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Me\MyBundle\Entity\HydraulicTestResult", mappedBy="idHydraulicTest")
 */
private $hydraulicTestResults;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->hydraulicTestResults = new ArrayCollection();
}
...
/**
 * Get hydraulicTestResults
 *
 * @return \Me\MyBundle\Entity\HydraulicTestResult
 */
public function getHydraulicTestResults()
{
    return $this->hydraulicTestResults;
}
}

class HydraulicTestResult
{...
/**
 * @var \Me\MyBundle\Entity\HydraulicTest
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Me\MyBundle\Entity\HydraulicTest", inversedBy="hydraulicTestResults")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_hydraulic_test", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $idHydraulicTest;
...
/**
 * Set idHydraulicTest
 *
 * @param \Me\MyBundle\Entity\HydraulicTest $idHydraulicTest
 *
 * @return HydraulicTestResult
 */
public function setIdHydraulicTest(\Me\MyBundle\Entity\HydraulicTest $idHydraulicTest = null)
{
    $this->idHydraulicTest = $idHydraulicTest;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get idHydraulicTest
 *
 * @return \Me\MyBundle\Entity\HydraulicTest
 */
public function getIdHydraulicTest()
{
    return $this->idHydraulicTest;
}
}
```

And this is now what I did in my controller

```
$HydraulicTest = new HydraulicTest();
$HydraulicTest->setTester('This is a test');
$hydraulicTestResult=  new HydraulicTestResult();
$hydraulicTestResult->setFluidTemperature(12);
$HydraulicTest->getHydraulicTestResults()->add($hydraulicTestResult);    
$hydraulicTestResult2=  new HydraulicTestResult();
$hydraulicTestResult2->setFluidTemperature(44);
$HydraulicTest->getHydraulicTestResults()->add($hydraulicTestResult2);
```

This works well and return to me the array collection when I display my entity

```
HydraulicTest {#1654 ▼
  -comment: "test"
  -validationComment: null
  -model: null
  -tester: "This is a test"
  -hydraulicTestResults: ArrayCollection {#2651 ▼
    -elements: array:2 [▼
      0 => HydraulicTestResult {#2652 ▼
        -temperature: 12
      }
      1 => HydraulicTestResult {#2653 ▼
        -temperature: 44
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Call that not work

```
$EntityHydraulicTest = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(HydraulicTest::class)->findOneById($id);
$EntityHydraulicTest->getHydraulicTestResults();
```

This always return me null for the ArrayCollection even if there is elements in the HydraulicTestResult in the database linked to the HydraulicTest entity

```
HydraulicTest {#2688 ▼
  -comment: "test"
  -validationComment: null
  -model: null
  -tester: null
  -id: 8
  -hydraulicTestResults: null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Before doing any of the bellow , check if you have some files under `resources/config/doctrine/` and remove them ( you can make a backup before removing them )  as symfony will ignore your annotations if it founds files there !

Reading this post about doctrine associations will help you get a better understanding of this problem : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

> When a bidirectional assocation is updated, Doctrine only checks on one of both sides for these changes. This is called the owning side of the association.

Doctrine checks only the `owning side` of your association which is `HydraulicTestResult`

> The owning side has to use the inversedBy attribute of the OneToOne, ManyToOne, or ManyToMany mapping declaration. The inversedBy attribute contains the name of the association-field on the inverse-side.
>
> ManyToOne is always the owning side of a bidirectional association.
>   OneToMany is always the inverse side of a bidirectional association.

For you code to work you have to do this  :

```
$HydraulicTest = new HydraulicTest();
$HydraulicTest->setTester('This is a test');
$hydraulicTestResult=  new HydraulicTestResult();
$hydraulicTestResult->setIdHydraulicTest($HydraulicTest);// add this line 
....
$em->persist($hydraulicTestResult);
$em->persist($HydraulicTest);
$em->flush();
```

or you can add a method in `HydraulicTestResult` class like this :

```
function addHydraulicTestResult(HydraulicTestResult $test){
    $this->hydraulicTestResults->add($test);
    $test->setIdHydraulicTest($this);
}
```

and then use it in you code :

```
$HydraulicTest = new HydraulicTest();
$HydraulicTest->setTester('This is a test');
$hydraulicTestResult=  new HydraulicTestResult();
$HydraulicTest->addHydraulicTestResult($hydraulicTestResult);
...
 ....
$em->persist($hydraulicTestResult);
$em->persist($HydraulicTest);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: There is something I don't understand. I only have the line $EntityHydraulicTest = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(HydraulicTest::class)->findOneById($id); I didn't have $hydraulicTestResult object. I think I am totally lost^^

Comment: I edited my answer to more clarify the code. Have you tried one of the suggesstions I mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes I understand better your answer now and it works when I flush. But the problem is when I try to retrive an hydraulicTest from the database. I didn't have any hydraulicTestResult return even if there is one in the database. I think I have to use a reporsitory query to join the hydraulicTestResult table.

Comment: you should not join to get results as `doctrine` 's goal is to avoid doing that each time. can you post the result of `Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($EntityHydraulicTest)` ?

Comment: The only explanation that I find here is that there is somewhere a code that you are not aware of that sets the collection `hydraulicTestResults` to null or you links are not saved in db. Can you show the outpout of this sql query please ( assuming you use mysql ) `select count (*) from  hydraulicTestResult where id_hydraulic_test = 8 `

Comment: I think I find the problem. My entity file is use the many to one, but the files under resources/config/doctrine/HydraulicTest.orm.xml and HydraulicTestResult.orm.xml don't reflect it. I think I have to configure them also. I don't know why they are not updated when I do a  doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: Oh no , you need to remove that folder , you either have to use annotation or .orm.xml files. remove the folder config/doctrine , clear the cache and test it should work.

Comment: It is ok now. Thanks a lot for your help. I think I never found it alone. I now only have entity with annotation and it works very well!!!!

Comment: I will update my answer to mention the .orm.xml files and then you can accept my answer hopefully.